# How to avoid DbContext Issues in Multithread Scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, transactions, savechanges

I'm working on a very big project, which is supposed to talk to a very old Command Base API, and perform lot of actions, which each of them must perform many commands to get to the point, and then I have to save the state of results.

Everybody talks to my DB, they add a record to my process queue, I read it, perform some action, return some results either in process queue itself or in a respected table.

The main pipeline is as the following image, I omit a lot of actions and locks.
    [image: enter code here]

DB is the EF DbContext, the black box, is action running in the main thread, which runs several actions and does this over and over till the application terminate.

The Orange Box, are the sub-thread who perform actions after they called by the main thread.

Previously I had 1 issue, where the DB went dead due to a transaction, but since must of the time I had 1 API in my queue or at most 2, and I only felt it under SQL management tools, I thought of fixing it later.

but newly, I felt the issue some time, but today I saw it,... I had a failed action, and then the application start to repeating the same process, over and over, without terminating it or doing any other, though it should return either success or error. so I trace it a little while and I notice it the failed spot (one of inner exception handler) which said I tried  to insert a duplicate key into the database, so I went and look at the Db changes, and I noticed that I have over five entry, which should only be one.

so I first thought of getting ride of changes before every `dB.SaveChange`, so I went over the web found some piece of code which renders all changes as unchanged.
so I start changing my application adding this piece of code:

```
lock(DbAction){
  ClearingDbContextChanges();
  AddResults() if there is any
  Change() if there is any
  Delete() if there is any
  SetEntity as Modified if there is any
  Db.SaveChanges()
}
```

then before I run the application I reach to the last spot, where I notice that I can't use this action anymore, and it renders some of my main action unusable.

Comment: "How to avoid DbContext Issues in Multithread Scenario" > don't reuse the same DbContext from multiple threads - create new DbContext every time you need.

Comment: And wouldn't it cause more trouble accessing same data, when DB put transactional lock on them?

Comment: I'd say it will never create more problems that reusing the same DbContext from multiple threads - that's a real no-no.

Comment: what about performance? several year ago, when i weren't still a professional programmer, i tried to copy the Hibernate structure, well now i know how far i was, BTW, i had no idea of MARS feature, and i poll connection for each concurrent action, still i remember, opening a connection would took  ~100ms, while fetching data, without Mixed Relation, would took maybe ~1ms. so won't it introduced a huge performance issue?

Comment: Connections are usually pooled, so when you create new context and make a query - it does _not_ necessary mean new connection is opened. It is usually just taken out of the pool. In general, work with EF context should go as follows: you need to do some logical operation, you create new context, do it, then dispose. Even in single-threaded scenarios. That's because EF context is designed with so called "unit of work" pattern. If you don't need to update objects later, you don't need to store context anywhere at all. Create (connection grabbed from pool), Select, dispose (back to pool).

Comment: Well i have this process, that at begin i get an object from, then after fetching, i go inside the thread, and i need to update it in the end of running thread to return it's state. so it's context is shared within the main and runners. But there are other actions, which perform after the runner perform some action, and before it ends... . so in here i have 2 Context side by side... if i want to save processes i have to call outer, if i want to save other, i call the inner, right? only this remain is locking issue with the DB itself, what can be best if i set my transaction to?

Comment: i remember the Transaction itself, or transaction scope it were, which we used in old type of programming without any ORM, had several type, which in each scenario one were prefered to the other, is there any suggestion, for my case ?

Comment: If you need to update\delete some object - you use the same context which this object was received from.As for transactions, I have hard time understanding what exactly happens in your case, so cannot help with that :) But you can carefully read transaction isolation levels (which levels exist, what they mean) and choose an appropriate one for your case. Though long-running transactions (select stuff, do a loong processing of it, save changes) it usually not very good idea. Often there are better ways (depending on situation).

Comment: well that's right, i have too see what happen, not just try predicting all. the issue is the system is reservation system, that every mismatch, and failure, can lead to many trouble both for people, and at some point, to lot of Financial loss only per one transaction, that's why i try to act pernickety

Comment: I think you're ready for a service-bus architecture.

Comment: @GertArnold and what is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
lock(DbAction) {
   // Modify DB 
}
```

Do **NOT** mix application locks and DB locks. You are asking for an undetectable deadlock. A Deadlock occurs when the lock wait chain has a cycle. The DB is capable of detecting such cycles and solve the deadlock (by choosing a victim and aborting its transaction). But when you combine application locks and DB locks, as you did, the wait chain can form a cycle *through the application locks*. Think Thread A holds DB lock 1 and waits for DbAction, and Thread 2 holds DbAction and waits for DB lock 1. These deadlock chains are *undetectable* by the DB and as such no deadlock is raised. Your app will stay deadlock forever (until explicitly killed).

Do not issue DB calls while holding an application `lock`. Never. Ever.

Now, for your issue: you exhibit typical ACID inconsistency issues. Your units of works seem to execute repeatedly (duplicate entries in DB) and/or save inconsistent state in DB (missing transaction scope?). One cannot guess what's wrong there.

Comment: well i do not want to lock DB, i want it to be unlocked, but i need transaction to go on, if something failed, this project is the one of those that blow up badly, so i needed to define them. I introduce Locks not to control DB, i wanted, but u reverted that part. i only use them to manage, which pool item shall pass and keep track of active/inactive sessions. also keep track of queue items, and totally i can say managing my processing pipeline, and the whole ~1 year that i work on this system, i didn't seem to cause any dead ends.

Comment: well i still didn't launch so many Pool Object and Requests at same time, as it was all tests, and debugs, but i don't think there are much bug with my system, I'm more than that afraid of RCW exceptions, since the API only run on windows forms, and it should be synchronous, i somehow take it out and put it on trade, but still it fails on dispose.